# View the same thumbnail picture on orientation change

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to get the Bitmap picture here to show in the ImageView after orientation change instead of the picture taken from the drawable folder. 
I know savedInstance can do this, but unsure how to use it for this. 
I've also tried onCofigureationChange(), but with no luck.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
    }
}

public void taBilde(View view) {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To ratain data in lifecycle changes you can use `ViewModel` from [this link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel).

**UPDATE**

I write a code for this solution in kotlin. You can write it in java.

```
import android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData
import android.arch.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel
import android.graphics.Bitmap


/**
 * Created by Amin on 9/6/2018.
 */
class ThumbnailHolderViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private var thumbnail: MutableLiveData<Bitmap>? = null

    fun setThumbnail(bitmap: Bitmap) {
        if (thumbnail == null) {
            thumbnail = MutableLiveData()
        }
        thumbnail?.value = bitmap
    }

    fun getThumbnail(): LiveData<Bitmap>? {
        return thumbnail
    }

}
```

to initialize the ViewModel in your activity:

```
val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ThumbnailHolderViewModel::class.java)
viewModel.setThumbnail(yourThumbnailBitmap)
```

and get the retaind data from it:

```
val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ThumbnailHolderViewModel::class.java)
viewModel.getThumbnail()?.observe(this, Observer<Bitmap?> { bitmap ->
    if (bitmap != null) {
        // do sth...
    }
})
```

Comment: This is only possible if you have a ViewModel class and not for all situations.

Comment: @UmangBurman: I write a sample code for that. It's applicable.

Comment: Yeah, this is possible because you have used a ViewModel class, that's what I said.. If you use a View Model class then only you can use it.